# php no me le una class de html, como poner zoom estilo lupa a una tabla?

Tags: php, html, zoom

buen dia
creo que no supe formular mi pregunta bien.
el problema que tengo es que quiero en una tabla me muestre un ZOOM estilo lupa de mi tabla productos al pasar el puntero encima, y claro enfrente los datos que requiero.

```html
<link type="text/css" href="../css/zoomy.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/zoomy.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/zoomy.min.js"></script>
  
  <script defer>
 $(function(){
  $('.zoom').zoomy({
   zoomSize: 256,
   round: true,
   border:'6px solid #fff'
  });
 });
```

eso lo tengo en la pagina html
y esto esta en un .php donde llamo para imprimir mi tabla

```
$row[]= "<td><a href=".$aRow['imag1']." class='zoom'><img src=".$aRow['imag1']." width=90 heigth=90 ></a></td>";
```

hice pruebas del html y de la class en una pagina separada, en una sola imagen y ahi si me funciona bien.
en el PHP simplemente no me le la class o no la relaciona con la funcion ZOOM

QUE PUEDO HACER?

Comment: Zoomy no es específico para imágenes [http://www.ymic3dworld.com/lightwindow2/ZoomyWcss3/zoomywcss3.html] ?

Comment: gracias.
lo que hice es poner mejor las imagenes en una pagina diferente